# I do not understand how to combine these two sql statements

Tags: sql

These are two functioning sql statements that I am trying to merge together into one statement. I am new to sql and I am not sure how to do this. I have tried using a union between the two statements but it did not work. On their own they each work.

Comment: If you want the rows from statement 2 to be appended to the rows returned by statement 1, just make the column definitions match then use `UNION`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, when your question says "it did not work", you should elaborate a bit, explaining that happened. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UNION` requires the same number (and compatible types) of columns.  Rather than selecting `*` in your first query explicitly select the column (`name`, `value`) that match up with the second query.